# How can I group datetime using Linq method syntax but ignoring time section

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC app written in C#, and I need to display sum of how many times people have viewed videos captured in a SQL database. I'm able to do it in SQL:

```
SELECT 
    CAST([Date] AS DATE),
    SUM([Views])
FROM
    db
WHERE 
    [DATE] >= '2022-01-28'
    AND [DATE] <= '2022-07-28'
GROUP BY
    CAST([Date] AS DATE)
```

But, now the problem is to translate it to Linq in my controller, this is what I have so far (where start and end date are variables):

```
var data = (Context.Where(w => w.Date >= startDate && w.Date <= endDate) 
                   .GroupBy(g => new { date = g.Date })
                   .Select(s => new { date = s.Key, sum = s.Sum(c => c.Views) })).ToList();
```

This will work but will group by date and time which has more rows.

For example, what my code returns:

- date = 3/3/2022 3:00:00 AM, sum = 1
- date = 3/3/2022 4:00:00 AM, sum = 2
- date = 3/3/2022 5:00:00 AM, sum = 3

What I want:

- date = 3/3/2022, sum = 6

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `EntityFunctions.TruncateTime`. I had in the past tried to put in a PR to allow using `DateTime.Date`, not sure if it ever landed.

```
var data = (Context
.Where(w => w.Date >= startDate && w.Date <= endDate) 
.GroupBy(g => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(g.Date))
.Select(s => new { date = s.Key, sum = s.Sum(c => c.Views) })
).ToList()
```

Comment: The OP hasn't indicated what version of EF they are using but it's worth noting that, if I'm not mistaken, `EntityFunctions` is not supported in EF Core.

Comment: I'm using EF 5.0.4 I don't believe EntityFunctions is supported. I do however get the option in Quick fixes to 'install package 'Entity Framework'' I'm assuming to latest version wich does support. I'm sure Arons answer will work, but wouldn't want to update just yet.

Comment: I believe the alternative for the `EntityFunctions` in the "classic" EF would be this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0&viewFallbackFrom=entity-framework-5.0.0

Not sure if it has the function you are looking for though